# How to use setNodeValue in SOAPUI to update XML request

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm new to SOAPUI and have several simple XML requests chained together. I want to use Groovy script to update an existing node on the Request side.

For example, I have GetRefData that starts:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="aaa" xmlns:abc="bbb">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <abc:RequestHeader>
         <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
         <MsgType>GetRefRq</MsgType>
      </abc:RequestHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
    etc...
```

I read the responses with no issues:

```
def GetRequestID = context.expand( '${GetRefData#Response#declare namespace abc=\'bbb\'; //abc:GetRefRq/MsgRqHeader/RequestId[1]}' )
```

How do I update the RequestId on the initial Request from 12345 to 53421? I've tried:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def request = context.expand('GetRefData#Request');
def requestHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(request);
requestHolder.namespaces["abc"] = "bbb";
def mypath = "//abc:GetRefRq/MsgRqHeader/RequestId[1]"
requestHolder.setNodeValue( mypath, "54321" )
```

But when I run it, although I get no errors and no updates.

Can someone please point this noob in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :)

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def request = context.expand('GetRefData#Request');
def requestHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(request);
//namespace declaration

// assuming your node is <bbb:RequestId>12345</bbb:RequestId>

def ns = "bbb"
requestHolder.setNodeValue("//"+ns+":RequestId", "54321" )
//to verify
log.info requestHolder.getNodeValue("//ns:RequestId" )
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it has certainly moved things along. I'm finding that the value is being set and the getNodeValue is shwoing the new value in the log `Fri Sep 18 11:41:45 EDT 2015:INFO:54321` but it doesn't seem to getting into the actual XML of the request.
Am i missing another step?

Comment: Yes... Sorry for missing it :)

'requestHolder.setNodeValue("//"+ns+":RequestId", "54321" )
requestHolder.updateProperty()'

That would do it :)

Comment: Perfect - that was it. Thanks, Eiston (I've also submitted an update on the solution to add this line).